# Extract data based on exact match of a string stored in a variable

Tags: bash, unix, sed, grep

So I was trying to extract data from a variable,

```
var="hi hello HI high" # --> This is the input
```

The pattern I wish to extract is kept in,

```
var2="hi" #  --> this is the pattern to be matched
```

If my input is the variable `var1`, then it should extract only the pattern in `var2`.

The output should technically have only:

```
hi
```

It should not pick up the other string which are partially matching the pattern:

```
hi HI high
```

I tried using:

```
echo $var|sed "s/.*\($var2\).*/\1/p"
```

and:

```
echo $var|grep "^$var2$"
```

It didn't work for me.

Also could you please suggest solutions that follow the POSIX standard as I need to implement this idea in Solaris and Linux.

Comment: So given `var="abcd abcd2 abcdz=abcds"` you want to extract `abcd` giving `abcd` as parameter. You either chose too-similar names or my eyes are getting tired, but I cannot see much difference here. Also, consider an [edit] to fix the format.

Comment: I hope this is not too confusing now..

Comment: `The o/p should only extract the search pattern in var2.`. This is also unclear. Show what would be the output for a given input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am interpreting the question right, you probably want this:

```
var2="hi"
re='\b(hi)\b'

var="hi hello HI=really"
[[ $var =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" || echo "no match"
hi

var="hi hello HI=really"
[[ $var =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" || echo "no match"
no match
```

- `=~` is used for regex matching in bash
- `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` represents captured group #1
- `\b` is used for word boundary (use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` on OSX)

**Using `sed`**:

```
sed "s/.*\<\($var2\)\>.*/\1/" <<< "$var"
hi
```

**Using `grep`:**

```
grep -oE "$re" <<< "$var"
hi
```

Comment: Hi Anubhav, exactly what I needed!!! Doe this work in all environments like solaris and Linux and AIX?

Comment: It should work as long as BASH is there. Otherwise you can try my `sed` and `grep` alternatives as well. Yes it will definitely work on Linux.

Comment: I've tested it on Linux. You should test it on AIX and let me know if this worked (or not).

Comment: sed is perfect, thanks for the answer @anubhava. Appreciate the help

Comment: done! Wish I could upvote the other answers as well :D

Answer (score 1):

Let's build up step by step

```
> echo "hi hello HI=really" | grep -o "hi"
hi
```

create a variable for the search pattern

```
> var2="hi"; echo "hi hello HI=really" | grep -o "$var2"
hi
```

create another variable for the source text

```
var2="hi"; var="hi hello HI=really"; echo "$var" | grep -o "$var2"
hi
```

I'm not sure of the practical value though.  Perhaps if you can state your original problem you'll get more useful help.

Comment: I think grep -O is unavailable in Linux, please correct me if I am wrong.. although the idea works perfectly, any equivalent solutions for this?

Comment: It's lowecase "o".  I highly doubt it's unavailable on your distribution.  It's a GNU tool.

Comment: My bad. It works correctly, @Karakfa. As you said lowercase "o"